# Heroku Posgres' DATABASE_URL cannot be loaded in Django's setting.py and application error occurs

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, django-rest-framework, environment-variables

When building an API server using Django+REST framework and uploading it to Heroku, hard-coding Heroku Postgres' DATABASE_URL in the DATABASES of setting.py as follows will work on Heroku without problems. (xxx is originally the information of DATABASE_URL, but we dare to hide it this time)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'HOST': 'xxx',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx,

    }
}
```

However, you can add a .env file to your Django project, stating the following (where xxx is the information originally entered for the DATABASE_URL, but we've dared to hide it this time)

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://xxxx
```

In setting.py

```
import dj_database_url
from dotenv import (
find_dotenv,
load_dotenv,
)
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600),
}
```

If I put something like this, it works in the local environment, but when I upload it to heroku, I get an application error.

Do you know the cause?

Comment: "hard-coding Heroku Postgre's DATABASE_URL in the DATABASES of setting.py as follows will work on Heroku without problems"—this is incorrect. The value of the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable can change at any time. It doesn't happen often, so you might think this is fine, but one day you'll find that your database connection is broken. _Always_ refer to the environment variable.

Comment: "However, you can add a .env file to your Django project"—you're mixing two things up here. Your `.env` file is _only_ for local development. On Heroku, just use its config vars. For PostgreSQL, you shouldn't be trying to set `DATABASE_URL`. The Heroku Postgres addon will set that for you. You just need to _read_ it. That's what `dj_database_url` is supposed to do, but it's completely unrelated to `dotenv`.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for getting back to me so quickly!

Yes, I see, I shouldn't hardcode it.

But as you say, I already set the DATABASE_URL in Heroku's config var, and

import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600),
}

is also in setting.py, but I get an application error.

Do you know what could be the cause?

Comment: "I already set the DATABASE_URL in Heroku's config var"—why are you trying to _set_ this value? Heroku sets it for you. You should never set this (except in development). Just _use it_ in your code.

Comment: @Chris   I am not hardcoding the DATABASE_URL in Heroku myself.

When I add-ons Heroku Postgres from "Resources" in the Heroku app, the DATABASE_URL is automatically registered, like you said " For PostgreSQL, you shouldn't be trying to set DATABASE_URL. "
But Heroku has application error , though dj_database_url is supposed to do as you said.

Comment: Application error can be caused by all kinds of things. Why do you think it is related to your database? Have you looked at your runtime logs by running `heroku logs`? What do they say?

Comment: @Chris You're right, I checked the heloku logs and that solved it! It was due to the fact that gunicorn was somehow uninstalled when it should have been installed previously. I've been struggling with this for a couple of days, so thank you very much.